# using asterisk in a variable as extension in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I want to define a variable that contain asterisk(*), like this

```
var=*.fits
```

The asterisk.fits is not the name of my file, but is name of some files with fits extension.
actually I want to define this variable to use it in the next stage:

```
ls "$var"
```

so that I see all files with .fits extension.

How can I do that? It seems that just writing just  `var=*.fits` does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use an array instead. var=(*.fits)

Comment: Following. jordanm's advice, the next step is `ls "${var[@]}"`

Comment: Thanks, but var=(*.fits) and then ls "$var" just list the first  *.fits file  and not more (not all of them).

Comment: Thank you so much.  Using ls "${var[@]}" lists all of those files.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the <s>wildcard</s> *assignment* to be stored in variable without <s>globbing</s> *word-splitting* you must quote it

```
var='*.fits *.txt'
var=*.fits
ls $var
```

globbing is not performed during an assignment `var=` (but word-splitting is)
as you can see you must not quote `$var` output in order to get it evaluated

the shell expand to whatever it finds at the moment of globbing

```
ls "$var"
ls: cannot access '*.fits': No such file or directory

ls $var
file1.fits file2.fits file3.fits
```

Comment: The quotes on the assignment are unnecessary; globbing is *never* performed during an assignment to a regular parameter.

Comment: The unquoted *expansion* is correct, assuming that no word-splitting will affect the result.

Comment: @chepner ah yes, i will never learn. also true for *var=\*.fits \*.txt \*.pdf* or better quoted in that case?

Comment: You are right, I should not quote. This was the problem.

Comment: @alecxs The *spaces* in that assignment need to be quoted, or else only `*.fits` is part of the assignment. `var=*.fits\ *.txt\ *.pdf` would suffice, though `var="*.fits *.txt *.pdf"` would be more common.

Comment: For clarity, in this case, the quotes do no *harm* either, right? They make no difference at all?